# unable to see some javascript line in viewsource on internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, html

In web application when i do view source on web page , i am unable to see below Javascript

"**class="igsortedtable_sortheader" onclick="ts_resortTable(this);return false;**"

but when I use "F12" developer tools the above javascript is visible. Why is like that? How we can hide some javascript in viewsource?

Comment: View Source shows you the raw HTML as it was delivered to the browser on the original HTTP request, before anything executed. F12 shows you the state of the page right now, after whatever custom or 3rd-party javascript has executed, which can dramatically change the DOM. Both are useful, so just know the difference so you can know which one is important to the task at hand.

Comment: view source is the page as it was loaded from the server. f12 dev tools is the LIVE dom, as it exists now, after any changes were made.